# wordpress elementor pro setting max-width on specific page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

In Wordpress working with Elementor Pro, you can set the max-width of different elements using the advanced/ Userdefined css.
However, I'm making a facebook landingpage that i want to only show as mobile-size. Where can I set the css-feature so it applies to not only specific elements on the page, but to the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you should be able to apply css in Page Settings (found in the gear in the lower left hand corner)/Advanced/Custom CSS. It works in the preview, but seems to disappear when published.